# How did the Greeks imagine the palace of the Olympians?

Tags: greek, olympus

The traditional view is that the palace of the Olympians resembled an ancient Greek [acropolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acropolis). However, I couldn't find any actual description of the palace or even parts of it from ancient writers.

How did the Greeks imagine the palace of the Olympians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoi.com has a nice article about [Olympos](http://www.theoi.com/Kosmos/Olympos.html), citing as main source Homer's *Iliad*.

> It was essentially an ancient akropolis--a fortified hill-top and
>   palace complex--located just below the peaks of Mount Olympos. The
>   golden gates of the heavenly fortress were guarded by the three Horai
>   (Horae) and it contained the palace of Zeus, lesser palaces for the
>   other gods, and stables for the immortal horses. The buildings were
>   built of stone with bronze foundations and were surrounded by
>   cloistered courtyards with golden pavements.
>
> The main structure was the palace of Zeus. It had a fairly simple
>   layout--as was typical of ancient Greek palaces--with a central hall,
>   private bedchambers and storage rooms. The golden-floored hall served
>   as both a council chamber and feast-hall for the Olympian gods and
>   provided them an expansive view of the world below allowing them to
>   observe mankind from the heights. The golden tables and tripods of the
>   feast were automatons animated by the divine smith Hephaistos
>   (Hephaestus), and trundled in and out of the hall as required.
>
> Before the palace of Zeus was a large, cloistered courtyard where the
>   full assembly of the gods would gather--including all of the earth-,
>   river- and sea-deities as well as nymphs. The peak of Olympos
>   functioned as the secondary seat or throne of Zeus, apart from the
>   rest of other gods.
>
> The Olympian akropolis lay above the clouds and the paths of the
>   stars, near the apex of the solid bronze-dome of the sky. It existed
>   in the zone known as the aither--the bright upper-air of heaven or
>   shining blue of the sky. The gods feasted on ambrosia and nectar,
>   substances collected from the meadows of the earth-encircling river
>   Okeanos or the smoke of sacrificial offerings wafting to heaven.

Among the most descriptive passages of the *Iliad* quoted in the article, you can find these:

> Afterwards when the light of the flaming sun went under they went away
>   each one to sleep in his home where for each one the far-renowned
>   strong-handed Hephaistos had built a house by means of his
>   craftsmanship and cunning. Zeus the Olympian and lord of the lightning
>   went to his own bed, where always he lay when sweet sleep came on him.
>   Going up the bed he slept and Hera of the gold throne (khrysothronos)
>   beside him.

<sup>Homer, Iliad 1. 493 ff</sup>

> The pressure held their heads on a line [the Greek soldiers], and they
>   whirled and fought like wolves, and Eris (Hate), the Lady of Sorrow,
>   was gladdened to watch them. She alone of all the immortals (theoi)
>   attended this action but the other immortals were not there, but sat
>   quietly remote and apart in their palaces (dômata), where for each one
>   of them a house had been built in splendour along the folds of
>   Olympos.

<sup>Homer, Iliad 11.72 ff</sup>

> She went into her chamber, which her beloved son Hephaistos had built
>   for her, and closed the leaves in the door-posts snugly with a secret
>   door-bar, and no other of the gods could open it. There entering she
>   drew shut the leaves of the shining door, then first from her adorable
>   body washed away all stains with ambrosia, and next anointed herself
>   with ambrosial sweet olive oil, which stood there in its fragrance
>   beside her, and from which, stirred in the house of Zeus by the golden
>   pavement, a fragrance was shaken forever forth, on earth and in
>   heaven.

<sup>Homer, Iliad 14.153 & 14.225 ff</sup>

The same quotes can be found in the English edition of the *Iliad* at the [Perseus site](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=en&inContent=true&q=olympus&doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0134), but in some cases they have different number citations: [Hom. Il. 1.493](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0134:book=1:card=493&highlight=olympus), [Hom. Il. 11.47](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0134:book=11:card=47&highlight=olympus), [Hom. Il. 14.154](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0134:book=14:card=154&highlight=olympus).

The [*Odyssey*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=en&inContent=true&q=olympus&doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0136) doesn't seem to add much, except that the weather there was quite fine:

> So saying, the goddess, flashing-eyed Athena, departed to Olympus,
>   where, they say, is the abode of the gods that stands fast forever.
>   Neither is it shaken by winds nor ever wet with rain, nor does snow
>   fall upon it, but the air is outspread clear and cloudless, and
>   over it hovers a radiant whiteness. Therein the blessed gods are glad
>   all their days, and thither went the flashing-eyed one, when she had
>   spoken all her word to the maiden.

<sup>[Hom. Od. 6.1](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0136:book=6:card=1&highlight=olympus)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

To the Greeks and later Romans Olympus was the mountain in northern Thessaly. Early Romans did not connect their Gods with Greek counterparts.

[Hesiod](http://www.sacred-texts.com/cla/hesiod/theogony.htm) has Olympus as a mountain

> ...and the peaks of snowy Olympus resound, and the homes of the immortals

As does Homer in the Iliad...

> Down he came, in fury, from the heights of Olympus...

He later [describes the Gods](http://www.poetryintranslation.com/PITBR/Greek/Iliad11.htm#BkXI1) as living

> ...in the fine houses built for them among the folds of Olympus.

The Roman [Ovid](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/9780195397703/student/archives/ovid/) also describes Olympus as a mountain

> I went down from lofty Olympus and, though a god...

Comment: I'm aware that Olympus is a mountain. The question is about the actual dwellings of the gods, the palace itself. The only part of the answer that somewhat addresses the question is your second Illiad quote.

Comment: That's about all you get really, it seems a fairly agrarian existence.

Comment: Well, this is merely speculation, but they should have some place to eat the 'nectar of the gods', I'd say, likely a dining room. Perhaps the layout of their dwelling would be similar to that of rich or mighty kings (minus the shrines to the gods, I think), or at least that would be likely for the Greeks to imagine if this isn't written down: the Greek gods, the Olympians in particular were very 'human' for a bunch of gods. We do now that Zeus lived as a baby in a cave for a while, but this is unlikely to be similar to his later residence.

Comment: @yannis My own best unsubstantiated guess is that the Greeks might have drawn a connection between mount Olympus, which is elevated over the surrounding world, and the buildings on the acropolis, which is elevated over the city state.